# django docker postgres s3 lambda

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose

AWS announced 4 months ago that "you can now package and deploy Lambda functions as container images", see here for [AWS announcement and sample code](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/).  I am trying to deploy my Django app in production using this service and setup CI/CD using GitHub.  I've been able to figure out the CI/CD deploying a simple Python app using Lambda (no S3 or RDS).  However, I don't know how to get Django, S3, Postgres, and Lambda to work together.  I am new to Docker and followed [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) However, the tutorial does not talk about how to serve the static files using S3 and how to get Lambda, Postgres, and S3 all in the container, persumably because this is a fairly new service.  I was wondering if anyone has successfully deployed a Django app for development purposes using these services and can share how the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, etc. should look like

Comment: I have the feeling you need to read a bit more what Lambda is and what it is meant for. While it is technically possible to run Docker images in Lambdas, it is not meant to be a hosting system for you to run a Database, Django etc. with Docker Compose. Lambdas are meant to run a _small function_ for a few seconds, at max. 900 seconds. [Have a look at this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65370498/190823).

Comment: Not according to this [full-stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/aws-lambda.html).  The main difference between EC2 and Lambda from what I understand is that Lambda abstracts out a lot of dev-op tasks and so you do not need to worry about load-balancer, etc. and you only pay for the traffic you've used as you are not blocking resources

Comment: You can build AWS Lambdas with Python. Yes. That is what the article is telling you. But you would need to decompose your Django app in frontend and backend. HTML files etc go into a S3 bucket. Your database on AWS RDS, your API is build on Lambdas etc. But it has nothing to do anymore with Django. Just deploying it to Lambdawon't make your webpage work. You will at least need to have CloudFront etc. You are probably better served with [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).

Comment: You are right that a full-stack web app needs RDS and static file config to work.  But, this is completely doable using a serverless stack.  I've seen many tutorials bragging about the advantages of deploying your web-app using Lambda over EC2.  Serverless deployment is now well-established. Here are some examples: [Zappa and Lambda](https://blog.logrocket.com/zappa-and-aws-lambda-for-serverless-django/) , [Lambda Vs. EC2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8Vh9-hsRBo).  Both Google and AWS now offer use of container technology with serverless deployment

Comment: It is doable. You can deploy Django to a Lambda. But then most those serverless advantages are going to be lost. Python is already one of the worst Lambda runtimes you can use in terms of execution duration and memory used compared to Go, NodeJS, .NET Core, Ruby and Java. It won't get any better with Django, it will get worse. As your question already shows: you are fighting the system (hosting static files  etc) because you are basically abusing it. Your problems can be solved, but it won't be a good solution.

Comment: I've not looked into the performance issue yet. Thanks for the early warning. I will definitely look into it. But, I've seen Django websites with moderate traffic using serverless on AWS and have used them without any lag time.  Have you looked into a performance comparison? It would save me and a lot of people a lot of time knowing these performance issues ahead of time

Comment: For anyone interested in [comparison between Lambda and EC2](https://www.simform.com/aws-lambda-vs-ec2/)

Comment: I have indeed looked into it. In fact at the moment I am preparing a Github repo with the Lambdas in every runtime. Looking at the current Lambdas Python and Java are the slowest in processing time (not init) and use the most memory. Remember: cost = execution duration * provisioned memory. And if you have latency sensitive applications (like web apps tend to be), Python might not be the right choice. And those are just for "normal" Lambdas. Django apps are probably slower and need more memory. In the end it is all about tradeoffs. You can do it, but again: maybe use Beanstalk or Fargate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I'll look into it for sure